# Why does explicitly calling operator<< on std::cout cause unexpected output?

Tags: c++, string, operator-overloading, iostream

I was simply curious about what would happen if I called `operator<<` on `std::cout` explicitly because I learnt that `a.operator()` is exactly the same as `a()`. So I do it and it prints something weird:

```
#include <iostream>

using std::cout;

int main()
{
    cout.operator<<("Hello World");
}
```

> `Output: 0x80486a0`

Oddly, it outputs an address (the address may be different for you but it should still be an address). I'm thinking this is the address of the string so I try dereferencing it to get it to output the string:

```
*( cout.operator<<("Hello World") );
```

But I get a very long error

> `no match for operator* in '*std::cout.std::basic_ostream<...`

I think this is pretty weird. Nothing of the `std::cout` definition would lead me to believe this would cause any different behavior; also given the fact that explicitly calling the operator function makes no difference (or *should* at least).

So why am I getting this output? Why am I receiving an address instead of the string itself when calling the operator explicitly? Is this even the address in memory or just garbage output? Any responses are appreciated.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The output operator for built-in strings, i.e., the on taking a `char const*` as argument, isn't a member of `std::ostream`. The operator taking a `char const*` is a non-member function would be called as

```
operator<< (std::cout, "Hello World");
```

There is, however, a member taking a `void const*` which formats the value of the pointer using hex notation. This member is the best match when passing any pointer explicitly to a member `operator<< ()` of `std::ostream`.

Dereferencing the results of a the `operator<<()` doesn't work: The operators return a `std::ostream&` which doesn't have a unary `operator*()` overloaded. If you meant to dereference the argument, you'd call it like so:

```
std:cout.operator<< (*"Hello World");
```

However, this would just derference the `char const*` the string literal decays to, yielding an individual character `H`. The character output function isn't a member function, either,  while the output operators for integers are, i.e., it would print character value of `H`. For a system using ASCII it would be `72`.

Comment: +1 it's a good answer, and it's christmas, and happy new year also! :-)

Answer (score 8):

I think the issue here is that the `operator <<` that prints a C-style string to an output stream is actually a *free function*, not a member function of `basic_ostream`.  However, `basic_ostream` does have an `operator<<` function that takes in a `void*` and prints out its address.  As a result, if you explicitly try calling `operator<<` as a member function, you're calling the version that prints out an address of the C-style string, rather than the free function that prints out the characters a string.

You can see this by calling

```
operator<< (std::cout, "Hello, world!");
```

Which actually *does* print the string.

Hope this helps!