# What does object.operator do?

Tags: c++

I saw the following code:

```
cout.operator << ("Hello");
```

And thought it would be the same as:

```
cout << "Hello";
```

But it prints:

```
0x46e030
```

How does it work? What can it do?

Comment: possibly [related](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14015824/why-does-explicitly-calling-operator-on-stdcout-cause-unexpected-output)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`object.operator<<(??);` is not *quite* the same as `std::ostream::operator<<(std::ostream&, ??)`, because it excludes non-member (free) functions.

The `std::ostream::operator<<` *members* are:

```
basic_ostream& operator<<( short value );
basic_ostream& operator<<( unsigned short value );
basic_ostream& operator<<( int value );
basic_ostream& operator<<( unsigned int value );
basic_ostream& operator<<( long value );
basic_ostream& operator<<( unsigned long value );
basic_ostream& operator<<( long long value );
basic_ostream& operator<<( unsigned long long value );
basic_ostream& operator<<( float value );
basic_ostream& operator<<( double value );
basic_ostream& operator<<( long double value );
basic_ostream& operator<<( bool value );
basic_ostream& operator<<( const void* value );
basic_ostream& operator<<( std::basic_streambuf<CharT, Traits>* sb);
basic_ostream& operator<<( basic_ostream& st, std::ios_base& (*func)(std::ios_base&) );
basic_ostream& operator<<( basic_ostream& st, std::basic_ios<CharT,Traits>& (*func)(std::basic_ios<CharT,Traits>&) );
basic_ostream& operator<<( basic_ostream& st, std::basic_ostream& (*func)(std::basic_ostream&) );
```

The lack of `const char*` might seem confusing, but recall that you can add *free* `operator<<` functions as well, in addition to the above members.  `<ostream>` includes these:

```
ostream& operator<<( ostream& os, CharT ch );
ostream& operator<<( ostream& os, char ch );
ostream& operator<<( ostream& os, char ch );
ostream& operator<<( ostream& os, signed char ch );
ostream& operator<<( ostream& os, unsigned char ch );
ostream& operator<<( ostream& os, const CharT* s );
ostream& operator<<( ostream& os, const char* s );
ostream& operator<<( ostream& os, const char* s );
ostream& operator<<( ostream& os, const signed char* s );
ostream& operator<<( ostream& os, const unsigned char* s );
template< class T >
ostream& operator<<( ostream&& os, const T& value );
```

By *specifically* calling out the `object.operator<<(??)` overload, you've told it *explicitly* not to use the free functions, and only use to use the member functions.  The best match for `"HELLO"` was the `void*` overload, so it printed the address of the string.

Comment: Oh I get it. So `cout << ""` is actually calling a free function that is not a member function of ostream? Interesting (and weird) that they put the ostream functions in `istream` as free functions...

Comment: Er, they're in `<ostream>`.  Sorry, that was a typo.  But yeah, the string literal overload is apparently a free function and not a member.  I'm have no idea why some are free and some members.  Really, they could/should all have been free IMO.

Answer (score 7):

The overload for the `operator<<` that prints strings is a free function. It's something like;

```
namespace std
{
    ostream & operator<<(ostream &, char const *);
}
```

(though I'm not certain that it's exactly that). It is *not* a member function of `std::ostream`. By selecting the member function explicitly, you get the one that prints pointer values.

Comment: I am confused. I use `cout.operator` but why the free operator function is called? Isn't it supposed to call the member function of cout?

Comment: @texasbruce: No, why would it? Just like `sin(5.0)` doesn't call `5.0.sin()`...