# ostream operator<< call parent ostream

Tags: c++, operator-keyword, ostream

code:

```
cout << "11122333" << endl;
```

expect:
11122333\n
result:
11122333\n
All right. 
code:

```
cout.operator<<("11122333");
cout.operator<<(endl);
```

expect:
11122333\n
result:
00B273F8\n
(or some other address, it's cast to `void*` :( )

trouble:
Want write class derived from `ostream`

```
class SomeStream : public ostream
{
  public:
  explicit SomeStream(streambuf* sb) : ostream(sb) { }
  template <typename T> SomeStream &operator <<(const T &val) 
  {
    std::ostream::operator<<(val); //Trouble in there!
    std::cout << "<<" << " " << typeid(T).name() << " " << val << std::endl;
    /*some other behavior*/
    return *this;
  }
  SomeStream &operator <<(ostream& (*val) (ostream&))
  {
    std::ostream::operator<<(val);
    /*some other behavior*/
    return *this;
  }
  SomeStream &operator <<(ios_base& (*val) (ios_base&))
  {
    std::ostream::operator<<(val);
    /*some other behavior*/
    return *this;
  }
};
```

When I call parent operator `std::ostream::operator<<(val);` val cast to `void*` and not normal work.
How it right to do? and why direct call `operator<<` for `ostream` work not same as indirect call.

Comment: The output `operator<<()` is a global template function not a member of `std::ostream`.

Comment: How about `(cout.operator<<)("11122333");`?

Comment: @Kilanny - It is actually `std::operator<<(cout, "11122333");`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does explicitly calling operator<< on std::cout cause unexpected output?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14015824/why-does-explicitly-calling-operator-on-stdcout-cause-unexpected-output)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The output `operator <<` for `const char*` is not a member of type `ostream`.
[Only those](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/operator_ltlt) overloads are member functions, one of them is for `void*`.
There are also [non-member overloads](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/operator_ltlt2).

There is workaround:

```
  template <typename T> SomeStream &operator <<(const T &val) 
  {
    static_cast<std::ostream&>(*this) << val; //Trouble in there!
    std::cout << "<<" << " " << typeid(T).name() << " " << val << std::endl;
    /*some other behavior*/
    return *this;
  }
```

Comment: only `static_cast<ostream&>(*this) << val;` -> work.  `static_cast<std::ostream>(*this) << val;` -> not work -> error C2248: 'std::basic_ostream<_Elem,_Traits>::basic_ostream' : cannot access private member declared in class